# Bootstrapping a React renderer: how do I get a reference to the root view at app startup?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I'm creating a [React renderer for NativeScript](https://github.com/shirakaba/react-nativescript) (i.e. to allow you to use React as a UI framework for NativeScript).

`ReactNativeScript.render()` (equivalent to the more well known `ReactDOM.render()`) needs a root node (A.K.A. container) to render into. Thus, I need to get a reference to the application's root view at startup time (which I'll use as the React root). However, I'm facing difficulties:

```js
/* app.ts */
import { on, run, launchEvent, getRootView } from "tns-core-modules/application";

console.log(getRootView());
// application root view is undefined

on(launchEvent, (data) => {
    console.log(data.root);
    // application launch event's data.root is undefined
});
run();
```

Clearly I am misunderstanding the application lifecycle here. How can I get a reference to the root view (frame) of the app at startup?

**Related bootstrapping processes:**

- [Nativescript Vue](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/blob/master/platform/nativescript/runtime/index.js) `runtime/index.js`
- [NativeScript Angular](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/1da4cfbadacfcba398519b274e426c1ab01d451d/nativescript-angular/platform-common.ts) `platform-common.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to create the root view yourself https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/blob/master/platform/nativescript/runtime/index.js#L73

First you create your root view, then you set it to `data.root`. Something like:

```
on(launchEvent, (data) => {
    const myComponent = new ReactComponent();
    data.root = myComponent.native;
});
```

Comment: That worked! Do you happen to know whether I should also update `data._window` or `data.ios`? I'm not sure what they're used for, exactly.

Comment: I don't think you need to. Vue and Angular don't seem to do it. Usually that's only needed at the component level, it's a reference to the native iOS/Android object (on a Button it's a reference to a `android.widgets.Button` on Android and UIButton on iOS)